# How to send such json post request in java with param in the url?

Tags: java

I have such a data. I don't know how to write it in java to send a post JSON request. Please help me! I can do it with curl in Windows, the code is:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "[{\"hostId\": \"01a31fc518c44166afe29a8694f4b3e8\",\"host\": \"WIN-PC_tttqa\",\"metric\": \"system.cpu.used1232\",\"timestamp\": 1457577649000,\"value\": 0,\"tags\": [\"location:aa\",\"level:high\"],\"type\": \"gauge\"}]" http://ip:port/openapi/v2/datapoints?api_key=fe01ce2a7fbac8fafaed7c982a04e229
```

[data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYi6Z.png)

You can see the data format in the `img` link of "data format", please show me the code, then I will try it immediately.

This is my test function:

```
public void sendPost() throws JSONException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {
        // 创建连接
        URL url = new URL(ADD_URL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // 设置http连接属性
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");


        // 设置http头 消息
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        // 添加 请求内容
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("api_key", "fe01ce2a7fbac8fafaed7c982a04e229");
        json.put("hostId", "01a31fc518c44166afe29a8694f4b3e8");
        json.put("host", "WIN-PC240");
        json.put("metric", "system.cpu.used1232");
        json.put("value", 0);
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        array.put("location:aaa");
        array.put("level:high");
        json.put("tags", array);
        json.put("type", "gauge");
        jsonArray.put(json);
        System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
        OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
        out.write(jsonArray.toString().getBytes());
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        // 读取响应
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        String lines;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        while ((lines = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines = new String(lines.getBytes(), "utf-8");
            sb.append(lines);
        }
        reader.close();
        // // 断开连接
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: _please show me the code_ No, please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: I showed my code, I don't know how to put the api_key, which is the parameter of the url,the server will return error 401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake. I thought post request can't follow "?param=..." in the URL. I just need to put the "api_key" in the URL instead of putting it in the JSON parameters.